# Clear a textarea via a button in javascript only

Tags: javascript, html

I only know how to use Javascript and HTML5

I have tried so many ways to clear textarea but they won't work

```
<textarea id="texti" placeholder="Place Text Here Or Paste Text"></textarea>

<button class="button" type="button" onclick="clear()">CLEAR</button>  
<script type="text/javascript">
function clear(){
document.getElementById("texti").innerHTML= "";
}
</script>
```

in the function part I have tried

```
document.getElementById("texti").value=0;

document.getElementById("texti").value="";
```

but apparently none of theme works in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. End your textarea tag
2. Use .value
3. Do NOT use reserved words like `clear`

```js
function clearIt() {
  document.getElementById("texti").value = "";
}
```

```html
<textarea id="texti" placeholder="Place Text Here Or Paste Text">XXX</textarea>

<button class="button" type="button" onclick="clearIt()">CLEAR</button>
```